# Printing markdown in VSCode uses different styling than on-screen

Tags: visual-studio-code, printing, markdown

When I go to print markdown from VSCode it does render the markdown, but it has a very different styling than the on-screen preview.  How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? It's common to have different stylesheets (or at least use media queries) for printing and on-screen viewing. What's "wrong" with the way it's printing?

Comment: Thanks Chris, perhaps I wasn't clear...In VSCode my markdown preview looks nice on screen, but when I print it, it looks completely different and ugly.  I can find no default markdown stylesheets referenced in VSCode settings, neither for on-screen markdown preview, nor for printed markdown preview.  I'd be happy to have the on-screen styles applied to the printed styles but I cant find either of them.  Thanks much.

Comment: To be clear, there IS a place in 'settings' (Markdown: Styles) that allows me to add a path to css files, but  there are no files there already, and no way that I can see to bind a css file to the PRINTED markdown.   I must be missing something....thx

Answer (score 2):

VS Code does not support the printing of markdown or anything else. For that you need a printing extension. There are only two of these, and I wrote the one that prints rendered markdown. I'm quite certain you're talking about mine because it has a Markdown: Styles setting and the other one doesn't.

Things have evolved substantially since I first wrote this reply, and stylesheets are now supported for both local and remote workspaces.

The styling used for Markdown preview is optimised for screen, the styling I have used is optimised for print. For example, I have used serifs for body text. They aren't the same, that's both intentional and desirable to most users. You can impose your own stylesheet.

---

### (this part is now obsolete)

There are settings that allow you to customise styling. It's not currently styled using a stylesheet because there are complications referencing that sort of asset in remoting environments.

To work around this I had to embed styles into the document. This has the unfortunate effect that you cannot override them with a separate CSS file. As a temporary measure, I have made available settings allowing you to customise the embedded styles.

I notice in the screen snap that I have specified "Blackadder ITC" as the font-family. This is not a typeface I would recommend, probably I was giving a demo. I sincerely hope this wasn't in shipped setting defaults. If that's why you think it's "ugly" then change the heading font-family to whatever typeface you prefer for headings. `sans-serif` will use the local default.

[image]